# how to use jquery datatable with bootstrap jumbotron with out using table tag

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have records in bootstrap jumbotron i want to add paging and sorting for it iam not using any table tags for it. will it possible to do paging with out table tag in jQuery Datatable please help me

**this is jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data =eval('${dealercatalog}');
    var table = $('#cataloglist form').DataTable( {
    "aaData": data,
    "aoColumns": [
    { "mData": "extcolor"}, 
    { "mData": "imagelist"},    
    { "mData": "vin"},
    { "mData": "make"},
    { "mData": "model"},
    { "mData": "type"},
    { "mData": "fueltype"},
    { "mData": "sellingprice"},
    { "mData": "dealeraddress"},
    { "mData": "description"},
    { "mData": "Selected"}
    ]
    });
    });
```

**This is my bootstrap jumbotron**

```
<c:forEach var="dc" items="${dealerCatalog}">
<c:url value="/updatect" var="url100"></c:url>
<form action="${url100}" name="upcat"
                        enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
                        <div class="jumbotron">
                      <div class="container">
                       <div class="row"> 
                        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-5 col-xs-4">
                            <img src="<c:url value="${dc.getFirstImage()}"/>" alt="Image 1" style="width:100%;">
                            <div> Use For FB Campaign                   
                                <label class="switch">
                                <c:choose>
                                <c:when test="${dc.isSelected()==true}">                                
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="ans" class="form-control" name="Selected"
                                     value="${dc.isSelected()}" checked="checked"/>
                                    </c:when>
                                    <c:otherwise>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="ans" class="form-control" name="Selected"
                                     value="${dc.isSelected()}"/>
                                    </c:otherwise>
                                    </c:choose>
                                    <span class="slider round"></span>
                                    </label>    

                                </div>
                            </div>



                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="row">
                             <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-xs-4">
                            <span class="ubh-jumbotron-label">Vin:</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-xs-8">
                             <span class="ubh-jumbotron-value">${dc.getVin()}</span>
                             </div>
                             </div>
                             </div>

                             <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="row">
                             <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-xs-4">
                            <span class="ubh-jumbotron-label">Type:</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-xs-8">
                             <span class="ubh-jumbotron-value">${dc.getType()}</span>
                             </div>
                             </div>
                             </div>
                             </div>


                            <div class="row">



                             <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="row">
                             <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-xs-4">
                            <span class="ubh-jumbotron-label">Make:</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-xs-8">
                             <span class="ubh-jumbotron-value">${dc.getMake()}</span>
                             </div>
                             </div>
                             </div>

                             <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="row">
                             <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-xs-4">
                            <span class="ubh-jumbotron-label">Model:</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-xs-8">
                             <span class="ubh-jumbotron-value">${dc.getModel()}</span>
                             </div>
                             </div>
                             </div>
                             </div>



                             <div class="row">


                             <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="row">
                             <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-xs-4">
                            <span class="ubh-jumbotron-label">Selling Price:</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-xs-4">
                            <fmt:setLocale value="en_US"/>
                             <span class="ubh-jumbotron-value"><fmt:formatNumber value ="${dc.getSellingprice()}" type = "currency"/></span>
                             </div>
                             </div>
                             </div>
                             <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="row">
                             <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-xs-4">
                            <span class="ubh-jumbotron-label">Ext Color:</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-xs-8">
                             <span class="ubh-jumbotron-value">${dc.getExtcolor()}</span>
                             </div>
                             </div>
                             </div>
                              </div>
                             <div class="row">


                            <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="row">
                             <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-xs-4">
                            <span class="ubh-jumbotron-label">Fuel Type:</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-xs-8">
                             <span class="ubh-jumbotron-value">${dc.getFueltype()}</span>
                             </div>
                             </div>
                             </div>
                             <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="row">
                             <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-xs-4">
                            <span class="ubh-jumbotron-label"> Dealer Address:</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-xs-8">
                             <span class="ubh-jumbotron-value">${dc.getDealeraddress()}</span>
                             </div>
                             </div>
                             </div>
                             </div>
                             <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="row">
                             <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                            <span class="ubh-jumbotron-label">Description:</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-11 col-xs-11">
                             <span class="ubh-jumbotron-value">${dc.getDescription()}</span>
                             </div>
                             </div>
                             </div>
                             </div>


                             </div>
                             </div>
                             </div>
                      </div>
                     </form>
                      </c:forEach>




</div>
```

I have records in bootstrap jumbotron i want to add paging and sorting for it iam 
not using any table tags  for it.  will it  possible  to do paging with out table tag in jQuery Datatable  please help me

Comment: Please provide a [minimal complete verifiable ecample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Stackoverflow isn't about other people doing the work for you.